# How to compose typeclasses in Scala?

Tags: scala, typeclass

I have code that looks like this:

```
/**
  * A divisor that operates on real numbers.
  */
case class RealDivisor(divisor: Long)
  extends Divisor[Double, Double]
  with Divisor[Long, Double] // ... with Divisor[Int, Double], etc.
  {

  override def divide(dividend: Double): Double =
    if (divisor != 0) dividend / divisor.toDouble else 0

  def divide(dividend: Long): Double = divide(dividend.toDouble)

}
```

I'd much rather be able to do something like this:

```
case class RealDivisor(divisor: Long) extends Divisor[A: Numeric] {
  // ...
}
```

Thus I'd only need to implement the `divide` method once. How would I do something like this?

Comment: `Numeric` isn't going to help very much, because it doesn't implement division. But if you follow `Numeric` as a guide, you'll find many of those instances didn't come for free. What is it that you're really looking for? The ability to divide a `Long` by other numeric types, or the ability to divide any numeric type by any numeric type?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351176/generic-numeric-division) might be instructive.

Comment: @MichaelZajac I want to be able to convert the type to `Double` so I can perform division on it; that's why I was using `Numeric`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the idea of a [*field*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)).

A `Field` typeclass is provided by e.g. [Spire](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/spire-math/spire_2.11/0.13.0/spire_2.11-0.13.0-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#spire.algebra.Field).

Comment: I'm not looking for division of one datatype by another of that same datatype. Sorry if my example was confusing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are though, even if you're not aware of it. The true tao is Field and projections from/to the data types you want to work with before/after division.

Comment: I'm seeing `abstract def div(x: A, y: A): A`-- definitely not what I want.

Comment: Also, although a projection may exist from `A` to `Long`, it does not exist the other way around.