# how to write a generic function in scala?

Tags: scala, generics

I want to calculate the mean of every two consecutive elements in array a, and return a new array. The parameter type T can be any of the numerical type such as Byte, Short, Int, Float, and Double. I don't know how to make it work. Thanks in advance!

```
def center[T](a: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
  for (i <- 0 until a.size - 1) yield (a(i) + a(i + 1)) / 2
}
```

Comment: Check contravariance and covariance:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html

Comment: Here it's more about type constraints, eg. `[T: Numeric]`

Comment: @Sid Variance applies to classes not methods so it has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue we have to deal with is that integer division produces an integer result: `(2+3)/2 == 2`

If we decide that we always want fractional results (maybe `Double`?) then it simplifies the task a bit. What's left is how to deal with input of any number type.

```
def center[N](a:Array[N])(implicit ev:Numeric[N]):Array[Double] = {
  import ev._
  if (a.lengthIs < 2) a.map(_.toDouble)
  else a.sliding(2)
        .map{case Array(a,b) => (a+b).toDouble/2.0}.toArray
}
```

testing:

```
center(Array(2, 3, 11, 4, 71))
//res0: Array[Double] = Array(2.5, 7.0, 7.5, 37.5)

center(Array(2.3, 1.1, 4.5, 7.1))
//res1: Array[Double] = Array(1.7, 2.8, 5.8)
```

Comment: Thank jwvh, this almost solve my problem. I know it is trick for returnning Array[T].

Comment: Returning type `Array[T]` is only difficult **if** A) you want `T` to handle both fractional and integral numbers, **and** B) division is required. Integral division is a different operation than fractional division. See [this rather old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40351176/4993128) for more details on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

This code example without dividing because of you should define your own typeclass for diving by integer value.

```
def center[T: Numeric](a: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
  a.sliding(2).map { case Array(f, s) => Numeric[T].plus(f, s) }.toArray
}
```